# How to use the sapui5 splitapp control to dynamically bind data

Tags: sapui5

I have the following data stored in a JSONModel：

```
{
  "threshold":[
    {"thresholdName":"1","person":[
        {"name":"a","age":12,"task":[{"taskName":"task1"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]},
        {"name":"b","age":13,"task":[{"taskName":"task4"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]},
        {"name":"c","age":14,"task":[{"taskName":"task7"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]}
    ]},
   {"thresholdName":"2","person":[
        {"name":"d","age":12,"task":[{"taskName":"task1"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]},
        {"name":"e","age":13,"task":[{"taskName":"task4"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]},
        {"name":"f","age":14,"task":[{"taskName":"task7"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]}
    ]},
    {"thresholdName":"3","person":[
        {"name":"g","age":12,"task":[{"taskName":"task1"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]},
        {"name":"h","age":13,"task":[{"taskName":"task4"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]},
        {"name":"i","age":14,"task":[{"taskName":"task7"},{"taskName":"task2"},{"taskName":"task3"}]}
    ]}         
  ]
}
```

Now I want to bind it to the splitApp control
The xmlview as follows:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.index"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <SplitApp id="SplitAppDemo" initialDetail="detail" initialMaster="master" orientationChange="onOrientationChange">
        <detailPages>
            <Page id="detail" title="Detail 1" class="sapUiStdPage">
                <content>                   
                 <Label text="Detail page 1" />
                 <Button text="Go to Detail page2" press="onPressNavToDetail" />
                </content>
            </Page>
            <Page id="detailDetail" title="Detail Detail" class="sapUiStdPage" showNavButton="true"
                  navButtonText="Back" navButtonPress="onPressDetailBack">
                <content>
                    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                        <Label text="This is Detail Page2" />
                        <Text text="Here you could change the Split Application mode. After the mode change, resize the browser window to see the difference in the master form behaviour." />
                        <RadioButtonGroup columns="1" width="500px" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom" select="onPressModeBtn">
                            <buttons>
 <RadioButton id="RB1-1" text="show/hide" selected="true" 
    custom:splitAppMode="ShowHideMode" />
    <RadioButton id="RB1-2" text="stretch/compress" 
   custom:splitAppMode="StretchCompressMode" />
    <RadioButton id="RB1-3" text="hide" custom:splitAppMode="HideMode" />
    <RadioButton id="RB1-4" text="popover" custom:splitAppMode="PopoverMode" />
                            </buttons>
                        </RadioButtonGroup>
                    </VBox>
                </content>
            </Page>
            <Page id="detail2" title="Detail 3 Page" class="sapUiStdPage" showNavButton="true"
                  navButtonText="Back" navButtonPress="onPressDetailBack">

                <content>
                    <Label text="This is Detail Page3" />
                    <Input/>
                    <Label text="Label 2" />
                    <Input/>
                    <Label text="Label 3" />
                    <Input/>
                    <Label text="Label 4" />
                    <Input/>
                    <Label text="Label 5" />
                    <Input/>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </detailPages>
        <masterPages>
            <Page id="master" title="threshold" icon="sap-icon://action" class="sapUiStdPage">
                <content>
                    <List id="list1" itemPress="onListItemPress" items="{path:'/threshold/'}">
                        <StandardListItem title="{thresholdName}" type="Navigation" press="onPressGoToMaster" ></StandardListItem>
                    </List>                                                                      
                </content>
            </Page>
            <Page id="master2" title="members" icon="sap-icon://action" class="sapUiStdPage" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onPressMasterBack">
                <content>
                    <List id="list2" itemPress="onListItemPress" items="{path:'/threshold/0/person'}" >
                            <StandardListItem title="{name}" type="Navigation" press="onPressGoToMaster3" ></StandardListItem>
                    </List>                                                 
                </content>
            </Page>
            <Page id="master3" title="taskflow" icon="sap-icon://action" class="sapUiStdPage" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onPressMasterBack">
                <content>
                    <List itemPress="onListItemPress" items="{path:'/threshold/0/person/0/task/'}">
                            <StandardListItem title="{taskName}" type="Active" custom:to="detail"></StandardListItem>
                    </List>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </masterPages>
    </SplitApp>
</mvc:View>
```

the controller.js as follows:

```
sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/m/MessageToast',
        'sap/ui/core/Fragment',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/Filter',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
    ], function(jQuery, MessageToast, Fragment, Controller, Filter, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";
    var CController = Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.index", {

        onInit: function(){
            var oModel =new JSONModel('model/threshold.json');          
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);

            this.getSplitAppObj().setHomeIcon({
                'phone':'phone-icon.png',
                'tablet':'tablet-icon.png',
                'icon':'desktop.ico'
            });
        },

        onOrientationChange: function(oEvent) {
            var bLandscapeOrientation = oEvent.getParameter("landscape"),
                sMsg = "Orientation now is: " + (bLandscapeOrientation ? "Landscape" : "Portrait");
            MessageToast.show(sMsg, {duration: 5000});
        },

        onPressNavToDetail : function(oEvent) {

            this.getSplitAppObj().to(this.createId("detailDetail"));
        },

        onPressDetailBack : function() {
            this.getSplitAppObj().backDetail();
        },

        onPressMasterBack : function() {            
            this.getSplitAppObj().backMaster();     
        },

        onPressGoToMaster : function(oEvent) {                      
            this.getSplitAppObj().toMaster(this.createId("master2"));
        },
        onPressGoToMaster3:function(){          
            this.getSplitAppObj().toMaster(this.createId("master3"));
        },  
        onListItemPress : function(oEvent) {
            var sToPageId = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getCustomData()[0].getValue();              
            this.getSplitAppObj().toDetail(this.createId(sToPageId));           
        },
        onPressModeBtn : function(oEvent) {
            var sSplitAppMode = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedButton().getCustomData()[0].getValue();
            this.getSplitAppObj().setMode(sSplitAppMode);
            MessageToast.show("Split Container mode is changed to: " + sSplitAppMode, {duration: 5000});
        }, 
        getSplitAppObj : function() {
            var result = this.byId("SplitAppDemo");
            if (!result) 
            {
     jQuery.sap.log.info("SplitApp object can't be found");
            }
            return result;
        }

    });

    return CController;

});
```

The effect is shown in Fig:[Click here to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXUa6.gif)

But I am using a static method of binding like this
`items="{path:'/threshold/'},items="{path:'/threshold/0/person'}"`,
`items="{path:'/threshold/0/person/0/task/'}"`

I want the items attribute to change with my last click.
So I would like to set the second page in the `onPressGoToMaster` event 
items, and then to the `StandardListItem` control binding `title` attribute to achieve dynamic binding. I try using:

- `this.getView ().ById ("list2").GetProperty ("items")`
- `this.getView ().ById ("list1").GetAggregation ("items")`
- `This.getView ().ById ("list2").GetItems ()`

and many other methods but I can not get the List control's `Items` property. How should I solve such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to the SplitApp, it is related to the general concept of data binding in UI5. Actually you are using an absolute binding path in all your pages, but at least in the second and third master page you need a relative binding path as the data to depends on previously selected model data. What is the difference between an absolute and a relative path:

An absolute binding path starts always with a slash and starts at the root of your data structure. Examples in your applications are:

```
/threshold
/threshold/0/person
/threshold/0/person/0/task
```

A relative binding path starts with a property and is resolved relative to a binding context which you can imagine as a pointer into your structure. You already make use of these relative paths. For example in the first master page you are using:

```
thresholdName
```

Which is resolved relative to each entry in your `threshold` array automatically using the binding context. You can learn more about binding paths [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9.html). As you are using a JSONModel you also need some knowledge about the corresponding binding syntax which is described [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116.html#loiod52e364907f94a3caeb4f5e5ad0cf302).

What you need to solve your problem is to obtain the binding context in your code and apply it to the subsequent master pages. I adopted your [example](https://jsbin.com/tepoxad/edit?html,console,output) at JS Bin. How does it work?

The press event handler obtains the binding context of the control which triggers the event. This is done with:

```
oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
```

This works in a generic way as the runtime automatically creates this binding context for you. For example the second item on the first master page has the binding context:

```
/threshold/1
```

You can pass this information with the [toMaster](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitContainer.html#toMaster) method. These information are available in the [beforeShow](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainerChild.html) event of the page control (see onInit method in the example). What you need to do know is to tell the runtime to use the provided information as binding context. This is done with method [bindElement](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#bindElement). In this example we can take the corresponding page directly from the passed event object and the path from the data object passed along with event:

```
let path = oEvent.data.path;
let page = oEvent.to;
page.bindElement(path);
```

Please note that `path` is just a name I used here, you are free to use another name. Furthermore `oEvent.to` works only in the SplitApp scenario. Please check the API if you handle events of other controls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely,Not only told me the inadequacies, I also learned how to use jsbin show sapui5 code。